# Hypernym for "driver" and "passenger"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

Is there a single word that covers any person who "rides" in a vehicle?

*Driver* would refer only to the person driving the vehicle.
*Passenger* can be used for everyone but not the driver.

How to refer to all of them? "People riding in a vehicle" seems too long.

"People being subject to conveyance"

Comment: "Occupants" ....

Comment: To add to what deadrat said, you may like to search for "occupants of the vehicle", you will get many results ---> https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22occupants+of+the+vehicle%22&ie=&oe=

Comment: Or *travellers*? Note: in the UK this can refer to people having a nomadic or unconventional lifestyle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Occupants

> A person, family, group, or organization that lives in, occupies, or has quarters or space in or on something:
>
> The occupant of a taxicab; The occupants of the building.

[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/occupant)

Comment: if I say "driving experience", does it include other occupants too, or does it apply only to the person driving the vehicle?

Comment: Usually, in order to have a "driving" experience you need to drive.

Comment: And in some cars (I'm thinking of Buicks) you can drive, and still not have a "driving experience".

Comment: Or in a google car......

Comment: This is right. The police usually refer to 'the occupants of the vehicle' in reporting car accidents, when covering both driver and passengers