# Word for anyone inside a car or bus, both passengers and driver

Tags: single-word-requests

Between German and English, there are quite equivalent words “Fahrer” / “driver” and “Passagier” / “passenger”.

But German has another word “Insasse” which is used for anyone inside a car or bus, that is driver, passengers, possibly the bus conductor if there is one.

Is there an English word for this at all? (Google explains the word correctly, but then suggests “inmate” which is completely wrong.)

Example in English: In a terrific car accident, the driver and his three passengers died.
Equivalent to the German sentence: In a terrific car accident, all four (Insassen) died.

Comment: I agree with the answers below that "occupant" is the word we would use but I would like to know whether "Insasse" can be used in other contexts as well. In English "occupant" can be used for someone who lives in a given property, someone who works in a given office and so on. If "Insasse" isn't used like that then "occupant" is not an exact translation.

Comment: "Terrific" isn't the correct word to describe a car accident. You want "terrible".

Comment: @BoldBen - _Occupant_ may be the nearest English word if there is no exact equivalent (as there sometimes isn't in another language).

Comment: Note that "inmate" is not a wrong translation of "Insasse", but rather another meaning of the word. It can be used for a person sitting in a car/vehicle or in a cell in jail.

Comment: @Laurel or Horrific.

Comment: @Laurel Unless you *really* didn't like those people...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hypernym for "driver" and "passenger"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269048/hypernym-for-driver-and-passenger)

Answer (score 31):

In English, we would call those *occupants*:

> **occupant** *noun*
>
> **a person who is in a car, room, seat, place, or position:**
>  <sub>*One of the occupants of the car was slightly injured.*</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Cambridge Dictionary —
> *occupy*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/occupant)</sub>

Here are some examples from the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* for *vehicle occupants*:

https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=100970269

Answer (score 13):

I'd suggest **occupant**

noun:
*a person who is in a car, room, seat, place, or position*

- One of the occupants of the car was slightly injured.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupant)

Answer (score 8):

Possibly [occupant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/occupant):

> a person who is in a car, room, seat, place, or position.

*In a terrific accident all four occupants were killed.*

Comment: Calling _occupants_ of interplanetary, most extraordinary, craft

Comment: BTW, that use of "terrific" is [no longer idiomatic](https://theweek.com/articles/446580/why-does-terrible-mean-bad-terrific-mean-good). "Terrific" has a positive connotation nowadays; for something negative, use "terrible".

Comment: @nanoman He must have really hated those 4 occupants.

Answer (score 2):

The U.S. airline industry uses “souls on board” in emergencies, which is more inclusive than passengers and crew, since some people on board may be neither.  It does not include cadavers, animals, or unborn babies.

I agree that “occupants” is good for this purpose.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/why-is-the-total-count-of-people-on-a-plane-given-as-the-number-of-souls-on-bo

Comment: I know it is an established expression, but "souls on board" always struck me as inappropriate in emergencies, because even for nonreligious people a sentence like "unfortunately five of the souls on board were killed in the crash" doesn't make sense (although it is clear what it is supposed to mean).

Comment: My understanding is that "souls" is very specifically meant to distinguish living people from e.g. bodies being transported in the cargo hold. This is important for rescue operations. (I have no idea whether this is the true reason; it wouldn't seem like confusing those would be a very common problem...)

Comment: The emergency rescue crew would like to be informed about that soulless unborn baby!

Comment: "Soul" has very definite meaning even outside of any religion.

Comment: @fraxinus Really? - please do give that definite meaning! I am not confident of what you will say about how it applies to monkeys, fish, ants, dead people or animals, not-yet-born people or animals, etc...

Comment: I sincerely hope the expression "souls on board" is never abbreviated. "The plane crashed with 25 SOBs" just sounds horrible.  :)